# Is it necessary to specify a column name?

Tags: go, go-gorm

I am making a Go project with gorm.

When creating a table, is it necessary to specify the column name in the option?
When you look at the formula and need mapping

```
ID`gorm: "column: user_id"
```

It need to write something like this

```
UserID int32 `gorm:" column: user_id "`
```

Isn't it wrong to realize that this is not necessary?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to tag the field of struct if you would like to have a name of column different than it is by default behavior.

This declaration `UserID int32` gives you `user_id` field. You could not specify the `gorm` tag if it is ok for you, but if you will do it - it is not a mistake.